# API 'QString' has already been set to version 1 on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pyqt4, pydev, enthought, python-sip

I'm getting following error **on starting debug session** in Eclipse for my code which uses Enthought Mayavi and PyQt as well.
Here is the error log in the console.

> ```
> pydev debugger: starting (pid: 2208)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.7.1.201409021729\pysrc\pydevd.py",
> ```
>
> line 2090, in 
>           debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
>         File "D:\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.7.1.201409021729\pysrc\pydevd.py",
>   line 1547, in run
>           pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
>         File "D:\src\Candls_PyQt\src\application.py", line 10, in 
>           sip.setapi("QString",2)
>       ValueError: API 'QString' has already been set to version 1

Here is my code snippet.

```python
from traits.etsconfig.api import ETSConfig
ETSConfig.toolkit = 'qt4'

import sip
sip.setapi("QString",2) 
sip.setapi("QVariant",2)
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
```

Comment: Are you sure that your very first line does not result in any `PyQt4` import somewhere? That's usually the case - `setapi` calls must happen before any PyQt import.

Comment: I don't know eclipse, but are you running your code in pylab mode? That would set the GUI backend before your snippet ran.

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue introduced in the latest version of the debugger.

The bug in PyDev is: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/452 (it was fixed already but it's still not in a released version).

A workaround for now would be manually applying the fix: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/af39f23bc884e9514aaaeede7b6e77e22b6823f6 in your local version of  pydev_monkey_qt.py (inside eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev/pysrc)